# Bison: how to access of value of previous non-terminal without using globals?

Tags: bison, yacc

I have two rules in my large grammar:

```
indexed_component
    : name '(' val_list ')' 
    ;

val_list
    : val          
    | val_list ',' val
    ;
```

How can access the value of 'name' within val_list ?

I know I can use a global variable, but this is highly recursive so I would have to use a stack and I want to avoid the bother.

Comment: If this is the *only* place you use val_list, you could access `$-1` in val_list's actions to access the name (if you use `%union` you'll need an explicit type tag here -- `$<type>-1`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is what is called an *inherited* attribute, which, unfortunately, yacc and bison don't really support.  You can "hack" it by accessing attributes with negative indexes, but that is error prone.

If you want to try using [btyacc](https://github.com/ChrisDodd/btyacc), it has some syntactic sugar to help with this (allowing them to be typechecked, at least).  You would write this as

```
indexed_component : name '(' val_list($1) ')' ;
val_list($name) : val
         | val_list($name) ',' val ;
```

and then in the actions on `val_list` you could access `$name`.  With a `%union` you would need to declare this properly with `%type`:

```
%union {
    char *str;
    struct list *list;
}

%type <str> name                // name gives a string
%type <list> val_list(<str>)    // val_list takes a string and gives a list
```

as I mentioned, this is just syntactic sugar in btyacc -- it ends up getting converted into inline actions with accesses to $0.  So it will get converted to:

```
indexed_component : name '(' { $<str>$ = $1; } val_list ')' ;
val_list : val
         | val_list ',' val ;
```

and uses of `$name` in the val_list actions would become `$<str>0`;

The way this works is that `$0` ends up being whatever is left on top of the yacc stack when the `val_list` rule is reduced and the values for the RHS of the rule are (notionally) popped -- it is the value for the last thing immediately before `val_list` on the RHS of whatever rule `val_list` appears on the RHS of.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can make a use of what's called a mid rule action in bison documentation. Here is what it could look like:

```
{%
std::string componentName:
%}
%union {
    char* id;
}
%type <id> name
%%
indexed_component : name { componentName = $1; } '(' val_list ')' ;

val_list : val
| val_list ',' val ;
```

That mid rule action will be here executed as soon as the `(` is fetched from the lexer. Then the value of `componentName` will be available in any semantic action of rule `val_list` because the mid rule action is executed before.

Documentation of mid rule actions:
https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Using-Midrule-Actions.html

EDIT:

But that solution require a global variable, which you didn't want to. Then the only other solution I can see is to build a syntax tree and propagate the value of the name as an inherited attribute in the `val_list` sub tree.